# HTTP Request and search bar function Swift

Tags: xcode, http, swift

I'm working on trying to figure out why this code isn't working well. I'm trying to search for an item using a search bar that filters through data to highlight anything that matches or comes close to that word. (Not sure if I even made a filter) So far I'm using the code that calls a list of items when a user spells out a specific name or reference of a business in the search bar. What am I doing wrong? How can I perform a search that will get the right data that is in the http request?

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!){

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchItem = searchBar.text
        performSearch(searchItem)
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }


func performSearch (text : String){

                    businessNames = [""]
                    businessID = [""]

                    var bodyData = "&key=(code)zqb&collection=www.(website).com_pcommdir&criteria=" + text.lowercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en")) + "&columnsAsAttributeList=&cartsiteid=1"

                    var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.(website).biz/codetemps/components/getAndroidDataVerity.cfm")
                    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),completionHandler:{ response, data, error in self.parseData(data) })

                    searchVar = 1
                }
```

Comment: I'm seeing that there is an NSPredict function that might work not sure though still looking

Comment: You should narrow this down. You throw a whole bunch of code at us (which obviously would not even compile) and do not tell us what you search, what your expected and your actual results are and you expect some help? Please help us too and give some simplified examples with the text you search, your search terms and your expected and actual results. Chances are, that you will solve the problem while narrowing it down btw.

Comment: I agree with you completely. I'm just having trouble trying to explain what I'm doing because this is very new to me and I worry that is not enough information. Thanks for the advice!